# diagramTypeProvider must not be null

Tags: eclipse, spring, jpa, editor, diagram

I am creating a `spring mvc` using `maven and Hibernate` as its database, I have a problem on JPA diagram editor I am using Eclipse mars.

After I enable the JPA in the project facets and added an entity in the `persistence.xml`, every time I click on the `Open diagram` it shows an error

> diagramTypeProvider must not be null

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, you have discovered a bug in Mars: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=472835

Follow the instructions there for a workaround.

Comment: Updating Graphiti worked for me (see below). The other steps in the workaround were not necessary: http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4

Answer (score 2):

Install Graphiti 0.11.4.v20150701-1432 from http://download.eclipse.org/graphiti/updates/0.11.4